# Understanding the $\text{SL}_{2}$-orbit theorem

Tags: complex-geometry, hodge-theory

I am trying to understand a meaning of Schmid's $\text{SL}_{2}$-orbit theorem. The nilpotent orbit theorem now seems quite clear to me (both its proof and why one would want to consider such theorem), but as a first-timer I still cannot quite understand what $\text{SL}_{2}$-orbit theorem tries to say. It seems to say that you can pick a more specified nilpotent orbit satisfying all those conditions which are still mysterious to me. I tried to find some other references other than Schmid's paper (not that it is not well-written, it is just too dense for me) but I failed. I hope someone could explain an intuition behind $\text{SL}_{2}$-orbit theorem. Also, it would be great if a proof could be sketched, as I would ultimately want to understand the proof of it.

Comment: Have you seen the exposition in Griffiths-Schmid ([1975](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=54:7868), pp. [108-114](http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~publ/studies/))? “In very general terms [it] says the following: given any one-parameter family of Hodge structures which becomes singular, one can equivariantly embed a copy of the upper half plane in the classifying space, such that (... ...)” “Although the proof of the theorem is technical, its basic idea can be described in simple terms. We shall do so below, in the hope that this may motivate and clarify the statement”.